# how to set final size(50dp) for an imageView so that it looks same size on any android device screen

Tags: android

Hi I have a drawable object which contains a app icon.The app icon are stored in drawable object in a `runtime` process, and then then setting that drawable object with an `ImageView`. But the size of the app icon changes depending on the device on which my app is running.I had set the width and height of `imageView` in xml as 50dp and used this code also:

```
image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setMaxHeight(50);
        image.setMaxWidth(50);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

But it didn't worked.So how can I set final size(50dp) for my `imageView` so that it can appear on same size on any android device screen.

Comment: Setting the value in xml should be enough (the above is essentially wrong since it deals with px). What results are you getting then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing

```
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
```

you are setting `width` and `height` in `pixels`. And for different devices as resulution changes it will not look same so you need to set those values in `density independent pixels(dp)`. Use following method to convert your unit from `dp` to `pixels` according to devices `density`.

```
public final class DimensionUtils {

    private static boolean isInitialised = false;
    private static float pixelsPerOneDp;

    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability.
    private DimensionUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    private static void initialise(View view) {
        pixelsPerOneDp = view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160f;
        isInitialised = true;
    }

    public static float pxToDp(View view, float px) {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            initialise(view);
        }

        return px / pixelsPerOneDp;
    }

    public static float dpToPx(View view, float dp) {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            initialise(view);
        }

        return dp * pixelsPerOneDp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting **width** and **height** in `xml` file is enough. You don't need to set it programmatically.

If you set width and height like this

```
image.setMaxHeight(50);
    image.setMaxWidth(50);
```

The value 50 is in pixel, not dp. An image with size 50x50 pixel will look different in different devices, because the devices have different dpi.

There are folders mdpi, hdpi, xhpdi and xxhdpi in your projects. 
If you want display your image in 50dp, you have to generate different files:

- image size 50x50 px (pixel) in folder mdpi
- image size 75x75 px in folder hdpi
- image size 100x100 px in folder xhdpi
- image size 150x150  px in folder xxhdpi

It is because in mdpi 1 px = 1 dp, in hdpi 1dp = 1.5 px, in xhdpi 1dp = 2px and in xxhdpi 1dp = 3px

**UPDATE** You can just generate one image with size 150x150 pixel and put it in folder xxhdpi. App will automatically scale your image to fit other density.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TypedValue` to get a `px` value based on supplied `dp`:

```
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```